# Using macros to create and rename a new sheet in Excel 2013

Tags: vba, excel

My objective is simple, when a certain field consists of text, I need a button that transfers this text into a sheet.

For example, I write "GOOGLE LTD", then I click that button, a new sheet is created and renamed too "GOOGLE LTD". Refer to picture below.

I have searched through the internet, but cannot find a simple tutorial that describes how to create and rename a sheet by using macros.

[image]

Comment: `I have searched through the internet` Why do I doubt that -_-

Comment: Use the Macro recorder to create a new sheet and name it. Look at the code, and learn how to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a backbone you will need to change the txt variable to = your range:

```
Sub create()
Dim txt As String
Dim sht As Worksheet
txt = ActiveSheet.Range("D4").value
Set sht = Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheet(Sheets.Count))
sht.Name = txt
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, the problem that occurs after I have set the button to the macro is this error message: "Compile error: Sub or Function not defined".